# Did arians have any kind of scriptural basis?

Tags: biblical-basis, christology, arianism

Did arians have any kind of scriptural basis for their teachings? If yes, what is it? What I am interested in here is the christology. Christ as created being.

Comment: Do you have any particular teaching in view?  Asking for the biblical basis for all Arian teaching is a bit much:)

Comment: @MikeBorden I scoped it to who Christ is, which I thought is what Arianism is about. I actually don't know much I guess.

Comment: Thanks, that marked duplicate works for me :-)